# French accent on Elsevier documentclass

Tags: accents, french

I seemes to me that the questions asked here about this do not work properly in my case.
I have:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\journal{Carbon}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red},citecolor={red},urlcolor={red}} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\affiliation{...é...}
\end{frontmatter}
```

However, I really cannot compile properly the 'é'. I have tried including `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` , `\usepackage[english,french]{babel}` but it didn't work.

Comment: Off-topic: `\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red},citecolor={red},urlcolor={red}}`  could be simplified to `\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=red}`.

Comment: Do you have the option of compiling your document with LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Thanks Mico. I am using Overleaf.

Comment: Overleaf is a platform, not a compiler. To change the compiler that Overleaf uses, first click on the "Menu" tab item. Then, in the lengthy drop-down menu, click in the Compiler box below "Settings" and select "LuaLaTeX". Then, see if your document compiles with the expected output for `é'`.

Comment: It works but at the same time, the font is quite strange. In particular it seems that some letters (like 'e') have very thin lines and thus appear glitchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `\affiliation` should be a set of “key-values”:

```
\affiliation{
  organization={Elsevier B.V.},
  addressline={Radarweg 29},
  postcode={1043 NX},
  city={Amsterdam},
  country={The Netherlands},
}
```

I tried

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\journal{Carbon}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{color}%,soul}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{soul}
%\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={red},citecolor={red},urlcolor={red}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\affiliation{
  organization=Ünivěršité,
}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

and it works.

Comment: are you using pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @Laura Yes, of course.